# React-Redux: error when importing Provider

Tags: webpack, react-redux

I have this error when I run webpack:

```
Webpack dev build for Rails
Hash: 33fd651f6a6e87a4ef46
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 5619ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   app-bundle.js  4.09 MB       0  [emitted]  app
vendor-bundle.js  1.89 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
   [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [0] multi vendor 76 bytes {1} [built]
    + 702 hidden modules

ERROR in ../~/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'imports' in /Users/matthieu/dev/MyProject/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components
 @ ../~/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js 6:13-29

ERROR in ../~/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'imports' in /Users/matthieu/dev/MyProject/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components
 @ ../~/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js 17:13-29
```

I have tried deleting `node_modules` and running `yarn install` again.
It appears I may have dependency troubles:

```
warning "react-redux@5.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "redux@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
```

My `package.json` files look like this:

```
# MyProject/package.json
{
  "name": "react-webpack-rails-tutorial",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.10.0",
    "npm": "3.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd client && npm install",
    "rails-server": "echo 'visit http://localhost:3000/hello_world' && foreman start -f Procfile.dev",
    "build:production:client": "(cd client && npm run build:production:client --silent)",
    "build:client": "(cd client && npm run build:client --silent",
    "build:dev:client": "(cd client && npm run build:dev:client --silent)",
    "test": "rspec"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^1.0.0-rc"
  }
}
```

and:

```
# MyProject/client/package.json
{
  "name": "react-webpack-rails-tutorial",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.10.0",
    "npm": "3.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:client": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.client.rails.config.js",
    "build:dev:client": "webpack -w --config webpack.client.rails.config.js",
    "build:production:client": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.client.rails.build.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.5",
    "axios": "^0.9.1",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jquery": "^2.2.2",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.1",
    "loader-utils": "^0.2.13",
    "lodash": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^0.14.8 || ^15.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8 || ^15.0.0",
    "react-on-rails": "5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

How can I fix this mess?

Comment: Can you explain purpose of this root package.json in your project?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus: no idea. It's an old project at my company that was started by someone else...

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. delete node_modules folder
2. change 1st package.json dependencies to

`"redux": "^2.0.0"`

3. rerun `npm i`

This should resolve your dependency issue.